# Printing repetitions of a String

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, arraylist

I have the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> processed;
processed = new ArrayList<String>();

int biggest=0;
int w=0;
for (int i=0; i<list.size();i++) {
    if(!processed.contains(list.get(i))) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i) + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, list.get(i)));
        processed.add(list.get(i));
    }
}

for (int i1=0; i1<list.size();i1++) {
    if ((Collections.frequency(list, list.get(i1)))> biggest) {
        biggest=(Collections.frequency(list, list.get(i1)));
        w=i1;
    }
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println ("max == " + list.get(w));
```

And the output is:

```
sorry: 4
bat: 1
train: 2
teddy: 2
ball: 2
max == sorry
```

I would like to sort the items from the most repetitions to the least. I know that I can use `Collections.Sort` to sort an array containing the repetitions. However, how can I match it with the name? For ex. if I sorted the array and it goes `[4, 2, 2, 2, 1]` how can I print: `Sorry:4, Teddy: 2, Train: 2, Ball: 2, Bat:1`

Comment: Are you using Java 8 ?

Comment: Look up "sorting by a property"

Comment: @RamachandranGA yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collections.sort` allows you to provide, as a second argument, a `Comparator` as a way of comparing to objects. So I would recommend creating a class with your word and its frequency, and then sorting a list of those.

Answer (score 0):

Use a HashMap to store pairs of name and repetitions:
`Map<String, Integer> frequeciesMap = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Java 8. This prints in the order of occurances of a String. If you want to limit it to the top repetition , you can do that using limit as well. The first Map has a frequency count , the second one is sorted. You can combine both into a long expression too. Hope this is inline with what you need!

```
ArrayList<String> processed = new ArrayList<String>();
processed.add("One");
processed.add("Two");
processed.add("Two");
processed.add("Three");
processed.add("Three");
processed.add("Three");
processed.add("Four");
processed.add("Four");
processed.add("Three");
Map<String, Long> counts = processed.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));


Map<String, Long> sortedCounts = counts.entrySet().stream().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Entry.comparingByValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, TreeMap::new));

sortedCounts.entrySet().stream()
   .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
Three=4
Four=2
Two=2
One=1
```